# Is there a good way to loop through hundreds of pages defined by a javascript pageNav value?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am doing a web scraping project and I am trying to crawl through hundreds of pages of search results and store the ID of the 100 links displayed on each page into a list. I have stored the link IDs for the first page, but I am looking for an efficient way to move to the next page, store the IDs, move to the next page, store the IDs, etc. I have attached my current code to store the IDs on the first page, as well as a screenshot of the website's code for page navigation of search results. I have tried using the 'click' button to no avail, and I can't seem to figure out how to use the pageNav value to create a good loop. Please let me know if you see a good way to approach this problem! I am very new to python and could very well be missing an easy solution. [developer side of page navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFSr5.png)

```html
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
import pandas as pd
#import tabula
import time
import os
#import module_name

PATH = "/Users/williamsheehan/Documents/ChromeDriver/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.implicitly_wait(15)

action = ActionChains(driver)

# go to equibase
driver.get("https://www.equibase.com/stats/View.cfm?tf=year&tb=horse")

# Horses by Foaling Year
horses_by_foaling_year = WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Foaling Year")))
horses_by_foaling_year.click()

# open menu of foaling years
year_menu = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("foalYearList"))

# 1998 
year_menu.select_by_value("1998")
# create list of horse ids
ids_1998 = []

# iterate through horses on page 1 and add ids to list
first_horses = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("horse")
for horse in first_horses:
    ids_1998.append(horse.get_attribute("id"))

                                                                                                     
                                                            
print(ids_1998)
```

Comment: You can target those webelements by creating an xpath for them.  Something like "//a[contains(@onclick, '"+ storedID + "')]"

Answer (score 1):

You're doing way more work than you have to. Selenium is not required for this. If you log your browser's network traffic, you can see that, once the page starts loading, your browser makes an XHR request to a REST API via HTTP GET, and the response is JSON, and contains all the horse information you could ever want. Not sure what your horse "ids" actually look like, but I'm almost certain they're part of the JSON response. Here's what part of the JSON response looks like:

[image]

---

```py
def main():
    import requests

    url = "https://www.equibase.com/Data.cfm/Stats/Horse/Year/Page"

    params = {
        "year": "2021",
        "page": "1",
        "sort": "EARNINGS",
        "dir": "A",
        "list": "N",
        "category": "A",
        "attribute_total": "1024",
        "set": "full",
        "race_breed_type": "TB",
        "_": "1612374713790"
    }

    response = requests.get(url, params=params)
    response.raise_for_status()

    horses = response.json()["stats"]

    for horse in horses:
        print(f"This horse is named \"{horse['horseName']}\" and its reference number is {horse['referenceNumber']}")
    
    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Output:

```
This horse is named "Knicks Go" and its reference number is 10049303
This horse is named "Jesus' Team" and its reference number is 10280418
This horse is named "Colonel Liam" and its reference number is 10280403
This horse is named "Independence Hall" and its reference number is 10292074
This horse is named "Largent" and its reference number is 10095939
This horse is named "Letruska" and its reference number is 10104837
This horse is named "Sleepy Eyes Todd" and its reference number is 10101749
This horse is named "Midnight Bourbon" and its reference number is 10400317
This horse is named "Wildman Jack" and its reference number is 10097023
This horse is named "Pacific Gale" and its reference number is 9900200
...
```

You can play around with the `page` key-value pair in the `params` query-string parameter dictionary to get results for horses on different pages.